# Estimating the Marginal Effect of a Misclassified Binary Regressor Without Instruments

Tags: econometrics, measurement-error, binary-data

In ordinary least squares, we can use an errors-in-variables model when one or more of the regressors are measured with additive noise to ameliorate the effects of attenuation bias. We just need to know the reliability $r = \left( 1-\frac{\text{noise variance}}{\text{total variance}} \right)$.

1. Is there an analogous result to estimate the effect of a misclassified binary regressor on a continuous or a binary outcome that does not rely on using an instrumental variable?
2. If I am willing to assume something about the misclassification errors, can I just divide the estimated coefficient by $(1-p-q)$, where those subtracted terms represent the Type I and II error rates to see how sensitive my estimates are?

---

Here's one [possible nonparametric regression approach](http://www.econ2.jhu.edu/people/hu/CHL-binary-indep.pdf) by Chen, Hu, and Lewbel. Has anyone ever used this on actual data that I can try to replicate to make sure I am doing this right?

Comment: +1 nice question. Unfortunately I don't know enough about it to answer this entirely hence just a comment, but I think the papers by [Meyer and Mittag (2013)](http://home.uchicago.edu/~mittag/papers/BCM.pdf) and [Lewbel (2007)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2006.00756.x/abstract) should help with the first point at least.